# Bootstrap Dropdown items not showing while clicking in ASP.NET Core MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I have created a nav bar in which I have added a Bootstrap dropdown named "Management", I have included all the Bootstrap css as well as Bootstrap js file but still when I run the application the even after clicking the down arrow on the drop down it's still not showing..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - eTickets</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/eTickets.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">eTickets</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                       <li class="navbar-nav ">
                           <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index"><i class="badge-info bi-film"></i>Movies</a>                   
                       </li>

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Managment
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Cinema" asp-action="index"><i class="bg-info bi-camera-reels"></i>Cinemas</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Producer" asp-action="index"><i class="bg-info bi-camera-reels"></i>Producers</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Actors" asp-action="index"><i class="bg-info bi-camera-reels"></i>Actors</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

 
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Filter" style="padding-right:25px">
                        <input name="searchString" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="search for a movie..." aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - eTickets
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please share your wwwroot folder structure where did you kept your reffered source file?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a nav bar in which I have added a Bootstrap dropdown
> named "Management", I have included all the Bootstrap css as well as
> Bootstrap js file but still when I run the application the even after clicking the down arrow on the drop down it's still not showing.

Well, first of all it would be nicer if you could share your wwwroot folder structures regarding how the source files has been kept or located there.

Most importantly, [UseStaticFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-in-web-root) middleware reference is also plays a vital role loading your JavaScript and jQuery or CSS file reference from your wwwroot folder. Make sure, you are using correct [StaticFiles middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-in-web-root) reference in accordance with middleware order.

Another important point is that, while you would run your application you should watch your, application network trace in browser and the console which of course help you digging into further insight of your issue whether the files got the correct reference. You can do as following:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** As you can see, I don't have correct reference for `eTickets.styles.css` so I got an error for that and anything related to eTickets.styles.css is not going to work accordingly. So please double check your file reference.

Investigating your issue:

Based on your shared code snippet and description, I have tried to reproduce your issue and I got it correct and its working fine also while clicking on the management dropdown, I can see the sub menus are loading as expected which you can see below:

[image]

Wwwroot Folder structure:

[image]

Program.cs file:

Double check your static file middleware reference in program.cs file which should have following references and order:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

[image]

**Note:** I hope something you are missing in reference or in middleware file. If you still need more details, please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)